# Gtk# Widgets Disappear/Don't Show Up Sometimes

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm building a Mono application using Gtk#. Sometimes, Gtk# widgets (just ordinary ones like TextView, TreeView, etc) just plain don't show up but show up fine in the user interface editor. For example, I have a bug report window

[image]

This is what its supposed to look like

[image]

This is what I get.

This particular build is running under Mono 4.0.2, and compiled under Windows (presumably using msbuild as opposed to gmcs). I'm not sure if that has something to do with it though.

It's also worth noting that I'm not doing any funky runtime stuff here: at the most, dynamically inserting text into the textviews. But this form I show as an example was invoked the same way for both screenshots (a menu opening a new instance of the form). This problem has plagued me since the start of the project.

One other thing: ocassionaly, I'll get a Gtk error in my output mentioning something about assertion failed but that also causes the disappearing widgets. What is going on here?

```
(PGE-Manager:7564): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_add: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(PGE-Manager:7564): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_child_set_property: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (child)' failed

(PGE-Manager:7564): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_child_set_property: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (child)' failed

(PGE-Manager:7564): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_container_child_set_property: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (child)' failed
```

Those are the logs (from another project but it's causing the same errors..)

Code

[The source file for the bug reporter form.](https://github.com/Luigifan/LuaScriptsManager/blob/master/Gtktester/BugReporter.cs)

[The GUI designer file for the bug reporter form.](https://github.com/Luigifan/LuaScriptsManager/blob/master/Gtktester/gtk-gui/Gtktester.BugReporter.cs)

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: @SkylerBrandt updated with links

Comment: I notice in your code that you are only silent reporting, and I'm assuming that doesn't show the BugReport window. What's the code look like when you do show the window.

Comment: The window is showed by triggering the Menu -> Bug Report menu item. Triggering it like that simply declares an instance of it and shows it. In the constructor for the bug reporter, it decalres an instance of my SysInfo class and then runs this.Build(); and then populates the info into the textview

Comment: Have you tried adding `this.ShowAll()` after `this.Build()`?

Comment: Interesting..I will try that. I managed to pull the exact errors from another project I'm working on now. I will update the original answer with that output

Comment: `this.Build()` does call `this.ShowAll()` at the end of the function. [Baltasarq also suggested here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875860/gtk-window-not-rendered-completely) calling `HideAll()` then `ShowAll()`.