# GTK# window not rendered completely

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, raspbian, gtk#

Right now, I am trying to develop a program using Mono and GTK# on a Debian (Raspbian) system.

The issue I'm facing is, that, completely randomly, the GUI (generated by the Stetic designer or its dynamic elements) isn't completely drawn, missing either a few characters from a Label-element or whole widgets, mostly those that were dynamically created. This is how it looks on a dialog window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFg2Q.jpg (text is cut off)

As soon as one window shows this issue, every other window has the same issues, sometimes missing whole widgets, even if those were created afterwards. The solution is usually to quit the program and reopen it, as it only randomly occurs.

This is how the constructor of most of my windows looks like (the part after `Build()` varies):

```
public partial class ErrorSolutionDialog : Gtk.Dialog
{
    public ErrorSolutionDialog (string errorMessage, string solutionHint)
    {
        this.WidthRequest = this.Screen.Width;
        this.HeightRequest = this.Screen.Height;
        this.Maximize ();
        this.Fullscreen ();
        this.KeepAbove = true;
        this.DestroyWithParent = false;
        Build ();

        this.ErrorMessage.Markup = "<b><span size='xx-large'>" + errorMessage + "</span></b>";
        this.SolutionHint.Text = solutionHint;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that at least part of the problem is that you're using the designer, and it calls *ShowAll()* inside *Build()*. Call *HideAll()* and then immediately *ShowAll()* just before ending the constructor.

Comment: @Baltasarq Thanks, that certainly worked for the cut off labels in the dialog. The missing widgets and some ignored operations still persist though... Generally, is it recommended to use the Stetic Designer at all? It seems to have some other issues too...

Comment: I wouldn't say that the use of the Stetic designer inside Xamarin Studio/Monodevelop is bad, but as any piece of software it certainly has some issues. Also, the use of any designer in any software environment will tie you to that development platform *forever*. Finally, the created source code will be hardly maintainable, apart from completely foreign for you. That's why I always recommend to get rid of the designer. You can follow a tutorial such as this one: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/ Believe me, it is easy and rewarding. And you'll have whole and through control of **your** code.

Comment: @Baltasarq The other window I was having issues with contained a TreeView and I did pretty much what you said, reimplemented it without Stetic, added the elements of the tree view together with all the other elements, added `showAll()` at the very end and it worked a lot better. Still having some issues with fullscreen mode and maximize but I solved it with some workarounds. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I'll put and extend the comment above as an answer. At least, for archive purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that the use of the Stetic designer inside Xamarin Studio/Monodevelop is bad, but as any piece of software it certainly has some issues.

Also, the use of any designer in any software environment will tie you to that development platform forever. Finally, the created source code will be hardly maintainable, apart from completely foreign for you.

That's why I always recommend to get rid of the designer. You can follow a [Gtk# tutorial such as this one](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp), and you'll find it is easy and rewarding. And you'll have whole and thorough control of **your** code.

The basics about Gtk# is creating a layout with VBoxes and HBoxes. For example, the following code creates a layout in which you'll have a TreeView and a TextView in a Dialog.

```
var swWin1 = new Gtk.ScrollWindow();
var swWin2 = new Gtk.ScrollWindow();

// TextView
this.txtView = new Gtk.TextView();
swWin1.AddWithViewport( this.txtView );

// TreeView
this.tvView = new Gtk.TreeView();
swWin2.AddWithViewport( this.tvView );

// Layout
var hBox = new HBox( false, 2 );
hBox.PackStart( swWin1, true, true, 5 );
hBox.PackStart( swWin2, true, true, 5 );
this.VBox.PackStart( hBox, true, true, 5 );
```

*PackStart()* is the method doing the magic in order to add a widget to a layout. The booleans tell Gtk to expand the widget. A **ScrollWindow** *adds* scrollbars to any widget.

Finally, my advice is for any action, use **Gtk.Action**, and call its methods *CreateMenuItem()* and *CreateToolItem()* in order to create menu entries and toobar buttons, instead of repeating the same code again and again.

Hope this helps.